# find the number of limit points of the set{$ \frac{1}{m} +\frac{1}{n}:m,n \in \Bbb N$}

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

> **Problem**:find the number of limit points {$ \frac{1}{m} +\frac{1}{n}:m,n \in \Bbb N$}
>
> **Solution**:$$ \lim_{(m,n)\to\infty}\frac{1}{m} +\frac{1}{n}$$
>
> $=0$
>
> So there is one limit point

Am I doing right ?

Answer is infinitely many limit points

Comment: We're missing the limit points $$\frac{1}{m}+\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{m}$$ for all $m \in \mathbb{N}$.  It's not apparent to me if there are others missing.

Comment: Actually the hard part is where you have to prove that there are no other limit points except $\{ 1/n: n \in\mathbb{N} \} \cup \{0\}$.

Comment: @some, not all that hard, as you know at least one summand must approach zero.

Comment: Answer is infinitely many limit points

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I don't know what approach you have in mind, but I solved this question as a problem in my Analysis I exam by showing that if $0<x<1$ is a real number not of the form $1/n$ we can find a neighborhood that doesn't contain any points other than itself and the proof wasn't really trivial. Now would you please tell me what you have in mind?

Comment: Pick some large number $N$. There are only finitely many numbers $(1/m)+(1/n)$ where both $m$ and $n$ are less than $N$, so eventually one of the two summands must be less than $1/N$. But $N$ was arbitrary, so the smaller summand must approach zero. That just leaves the larger summand which, if it's approaching a limit, must be approaching zero, or eventually constant.

Comment: A COMPLETE PROOF IS HERE:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/930646/to-find-limit-points-of-the-set-frac1n-frac1m-n-m-1-2-3/1217297#1217297

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the limit points are only  $\{\frac{1}{n}: n \in \mathbb N\} \cup 0$

as $1+\frac{1}{n} \rightarrow 1$

similarly $\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{n}\rightarrow \frac{1}{m}$ where $m$ is fixed and $n$ varies.